# How to use EXForm with a dynamically created cells

Tags: ios, forms

I'm looking at using [EZForm](https://github.com/chrismiles/EZForm) in an iOS Swift app.

The field details are retrieved from a cloud service and so created dynamically. Has anyone an example of where in a view controller class to setup EZForm to manage the fields when the cells are dynamically managed rather than statically created with @property references?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic table cells are not supported.
https://github.com/chrismiles/EZForm/issues/50